# What's a good alternative to 'sit on one's head'?

Tags: phrases, expressions

My student often uses the phrase 'sit on one's head' when she describes noisy and restless children that don't give their parents or other people around any personal space running around and playing in sentences like 'It is easier to work in the office than at home where you have children who sit on your head'. Does it sound OK and mean what she means in English? Is there a better alternative to say the same thing?

Comment: [**Pester**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pester).

Comment: I've never heard the expression.

Comment: More informal, (BrE) is _do one's head in_, as in "these noisy kids do my head in".

Comment: it's actually a expression that is used in Hindi

Answer (score 3):

It's not an expression I'm familiar with, and it sounds a little odd to me, but in context it's fairly clear what she means. Without the context provided in your sentence I would not have guessed the meaning.

A more common English idiom would be to say that the children are "[in your hair](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+your+hair)", which means "Irritating one, especially by impeding or interfering with one's activity or productivity". So for example:

*It's easier to work in the office where I don't have the kids in my hair all day.*

Answer (score 0):

There are many words and expressions that you could use here.

A single word would be ***[pester](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pester)***.

If the children are making noise and annoying you, you could say ***the children are setting my teeth on the edge.***

> If something, especially a noise, sets your teeth on edge, it annoys you very much. [[Cambridge English Dictionary]](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/set-sb-s-teeth-on-edge)

You could also say *[**the children are driving me round the bend**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/drive+round+the+bend)* or ***the children are getting on my nerves***.